# Custom post type returning 404 after changing permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'destination'.

What I add some destinations, I end up with permalinks like:

```
https://www.sitename.com/destination/destinations/asia/united-arab-emirates/abu-dhabi/
```

What I want to do is remove the category base of the CPT from the url, namely 'destination'.

For this I installed a plugin called 'Remove CPT base' which turns my links into:

```
https://www.sitename.com/destinations/asia/united-arab-emirates/abu-dhabi/
```

This is what I want, but now when I click the link, I am routed to 404 page.

When I go to Permalinks and change permalink to something like: `https://www.sitename.com/extra/%category%/%postname%`

This ends up in `https://www.sitename.com/extra/destinations/asia/united-arab-emirates/abu-dhabi`

This url works but I don't want 'extra' in there.

What must I do to stop that 404 page from coming up?

Comment: Quite a long thread, but one of the answers on here may be of some use https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls